# How to use notebook as external video capture card

Tags: video-capture

sorry if wrong session, but i've been looking everywhere and i can't find an answer.

I have a youtube channel and i want to improve my recording. I use the same computer to play and record. But i have one laptop, i was wondering if there is any way to use my laptop to record the gameplay i play on the computer.

In other words, i want to use my laptop as an external capture card.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop would have to have a built-in hardware video capture card, which is doubtful.  It is rare for a laptop to have a video-in port - usually it will only have a video-out (like for an external display).  You may be able to find a USB-based video capture card that you could connect to the laptop however.

Comment: Any suggestions of what i should buy? I think my laptop only have a video out, HDMI / RGB.

Comment: Hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic  here, sorry... you could try asking on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/